# CartThrob: Global options groups all in one select

Tags: cartthrob

I am using CartThrob's global options, with the multi group fieldtype to allow multiple groups to be selected.

What I need is to display all of the groups options all inside one select menu to allow the user to add any to the cart.

When I use this code inside the add to cart form:

`{exp:cartthrob:item_options entry_id="{entry_id}"}
        {options}
    {option_name} - {price}
        {/options} 
    {/exp:cartthrob:item_options}`

*** Stack exchange is removing a open select and close select either side of the code above.

The select is created with all options from all groups, but when an item is added to the cart, it has a price of 0.00.

If I use this code:

`{exp:cartthrob:item_options entry_id="{entry_id}"}
    {select class="print-select"} 
        {if option_first_row}

          Choose a your option...
        {/if}
        {option_name} - {price}
    {/select}
{/exp:cartthrob:item_options}`

Each group is in a different select, but the price works...

How can I get it to work inside one select?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don' think this can be done automatically with a native CartThrob tag. However, if you're outputting the CartThrob field data between `{exp:channel:entries}` tags, you could just use the custom fields of each price modifier fields within a multi select tag like so to group:

```
<select multiple>
    {first_price_modifier_field}
        {if first_row}<optgroup label="First Label Name">{/if}
            <option value="{option_value}">{option_name}</option>
        {if last_row}</optgroup>{/if}
    {/first_price_modifier_field}

    {second_price_modifier_field}
        {if first_row}<optgroup label="Second Label Name">{/if}
            <option value="{option_value}">{option_name}</option>
        {if last_row}</optgroup>{/if}
    {/second_price_modifier_field}
</select>
```

#### Update

You can't actually group all price modifier fields into one select group since each select menu needs to have it's own unique `name=` for CT to update pricing accordingly for that product:

```
<select name="item_options[first_price_modifier_field]">
```